# How to pull specific json fields without specific structure

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a flutter app that runs from a headless site. I'm looking at parsing a JSON object for the fields and values. Something like this:

```
{
    "content": {
        "fields": [{
            "label": "Vehicle Type",
            "fieldFormattedVal": "Cars and Trucks"
        }, {
            "label": "Brand",
            "fieldFormattedVal": "JLB Racing"
        }, {
            "label": "Model",
            "fieldFormattedVal": "Cheetah"
        }, {
            "label": "Scale",
            "fieldFormattedVal": "1\/10"
        }, {
            "label": "Completion Level",
            "fieldFormattedVal": "Ready-to-Run"
        }, {
            "label": "Body Type",
            "fieldFormattedVal": "Basher"
        }, {
            "label": "Ground Clearance",
            "fieldFormattedVal": false
        }, {
            "label": "Tire Diameter",
            "fieldFormattedVal": false
        }, {
            "label": "Motor Type",
            "fieldFormattedVal": "Brushless"
        }]
    }
}
```

Currently I'm able to get fields with a specific structure like json['content']['id'], but I don't know how I can get an individual field like the Vehicle Type.

How could I adapt this function to work with the individual fields?

```
class Vehicle {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String defImage;
  final String vehicleType;
  final String brand;

  Vehicle({this.id, this.title, this.url, this.defImage, this.vehicleType, this.brand});

  factory Vehicle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    return Vehicle(
      id: json['id'] ?? '',
      title: json['title'] ?? '',
      url: json['[url]'] ?? '',
      defImage: json['[fileName]'] ?? '',
      //vehicleType
      //brand
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: What if the fields aren't always returned in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

```dart
var response  = await http.get(url);

var data = json.decode(response.body);



var vehicalType = data['content']['fields'][0]['label'];//will get you "Vehicle Type"

var brand = data['content']['fields'][1]['label'];//will get you "Brand"
```

Comment: I'll edit my original question, but what if the field order wasn't always set? I'd need to loop through the fields somehow

Comment: loop through all keys and use condition to check.